# jQuery Slideup and Fadein Effect at the same Time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm learning new stuff with jQuery here and I have seen a effect that I like [link here](http://pexetothemes.com/demos/mineral_wp/)

Meet my Team section. As you can see if you scroll down the circle slidesup and fades in at the same time. I tried to replicate that effect.  Here's my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eVRLd/5/)

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $('#thumbnails-cont').offset().top-$(window).height()) {
        $("#thumbnails img").animate({opacity: 1, bottom: 0})
    }
});
```

Comment: We're not here to code for free, at least tell and show us what you've tried that didn't work.

Comment: Just use fade methods http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/fading/ such as `fadeIn()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to work with the `queue` property to play animations simultaneously.

Working fiddle: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/eVRLd/13/)

Basic code:

```
$(function() {
    $(".thumbnail").animate({ opacity: 1 }, { duration: 1200, queue: false });
    $(".thumbnail").animate({ "margin-top": "0px" }, { duration: 1200, queue: false });
});
```

Read [this](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) for more information about the animation function in `jQuery`.
I hope I could help you a bit :)